About android Studio Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
Now my buttons is cutomized with "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar", but I cant put a Bottom navigation bar because of it.If I will remove the "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" my buttons will be messed but I can put navigation bar, why's that?
I tried vice-versa the themes but does not work at all, can someone pls help me?

Instead of using Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar directly, you can create a custom theme that extends Theme.AppCompat.Light and modifies the necessary attributes to exclude the action bar while ensuring the Bottom Navigation Bar is displayed properly.
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!-- Include other customizations here -->
</style>


can you please teach me step by step? Im sorry im just a beginner

What are your expectations can please attach the screenshot to it.

Please add your custom button style code also

I just finished it now, thankyou bro
